# How to pass a selector into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure this is a noob question so go easy on me. I would like to pass a selector (if it exists) as a parameter into a function. This is what my code looks like:

```
function updateLinkedElements(element) {
    process the element;
}

// Ensure that the related elements is set properly on initialization.
$('#edit-type-config-associated-element').updateLinkedElements(this);
```

I want to pass the selector identified by #edit-type-config-associated-element to the function updateLinkedElements. The catch here is that I would like this function to be called when the selector exists (currently it is dynamically loaded).

Will this work? Or do I need to do this a different way?

Thanks

Comment: This won't work, you'll have to create a jQuery plugin to enable that syntax (without `this` at the end). See http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a method like that, you make it a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.updateLinkedElements = function(){
  return this.each(function(i, el){
    // process element el
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
$('#edit-type-config-associated-element').updateLinkedElements();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use that syntax, but you have to essentially create a jQuery plugin to do it.  For example:

```
(function($){  
    $.fn.updateLinkedElements = function() {  
        return this.each(function() {  
            // use $(this) to access any elements matched by the selector
        });  
    };  
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not do this:

```
updateLinkedElements($("#edit-type-config-associated-element"));
```

Comment: Is this a question, or an answer? It does sound a bit like a question.

Answer (score 0):

No because your function is not a method of the jQuery object.  Just do:

```
updateLinkedElement($('#edit-type-config-associated-element')
```

If it turns out that you will want to do this with multiple elements from the selector use each() 
http://api.jquery.com/each/

Then it would become:

```
$(<selector>).each(function() { updateLinkedElement(this); });
```

Answer (score 0):

use just `$('#edit-type-config-associated-element')` as the selector

Answer (score 0):

you can do two things to call a function defined in the manner above with a parameter of an object - either pass that selector as a string and target the element within the function...

```
updateLinkedElements('#edit-type-config-associated-element');
```

or secondly grab the element beforehand and pass that object as a parameter to the function

```
var el = document.getElementById('#edit-type-config-associated-element');

updateLinkedElements(el);
```

if your looking to use the jquery dot notation you would use the above method to make a 'plugin'